# Converting 5m DTM Raster to 0.5 m resolution in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, raster-conversion, multi-resolution-raster

I have 2 rasters (0.5m and 5m resolution respectively). There are some areas which the 0.5m raster doesn't cover. For these areas, I want to use the 5m raster. How do I merge these rasters into one resolution of 0.5m?

I have used r.patch, but the raster resolution comes to be 5m in it. I want the resultant raster as 0.5m. How do I resample the 5m raster to 0.5m so that it can be then used to patch using `r.patch` in QGIS 3.28.6?

Comment: You can try `r.resample` for resampling the 5 m raster and later run `r.patch`.

Answer (score 4):

The Warp (Reproject) tool will resample for you.

You need to set the Output file resolution to 0.5 in your case, and also pick an appropriate Resampling method:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Resampling 5 m pixels into 0.5 m pixel size is waste of disk space but it may be necessary. However, with QGIS it should be possible to use the GDAL virtual format (VRT) without resampling. See the documentation of the gdalbuildvrt utility https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html. Option "highest" should be good for you.

> **-resolution** {highest|lowest|average|user}

> In case the resolution of all input files is not the same, the -resolution flag enables the user
> to control the way the output resolution is computed.
>
> highest will pick the smallest values of pixel dimensions within the
> set of source rasters.
>
> lowest will pick the largest values of pixel dimensions within the set
> of source rasters.
>
> average is the default and will compute an average of pixel dimensions
> within the set of source rasters.
>
> user must be used in combination with the -tr option to specify the
> target resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Resampling tool from SAGA. In the field of cellsize you put the wanted output resolution (0.5m), in the Grids field you put the raster file you want to resample.
[image]

Then you can use either patch or merge your two raster files.